# Pass data from the current Activity to a paused Activity in different apk?

Tags: android

I have a custom-made voice commander that controls my application.
They are in two different apk and activities.

When my application is not created, voice commander creates it and pass data by Bundle.
But when my application is already created, voice commander will only bring my application to front. The data in Bundle can't be got!

I tried to override "onNewIntent()", but it wound not fire.

My App will run as below:

My app on: **onCreate -> onResume**
Voice commander on: **onPause -> onStop**
 
Voice commander send bundle to startActivity my app: **onRestart -> onResume**

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [onNewIntent(Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29). Your application's manifest must declare a specific `launchMode` or the Intent in `startActivity(Intent)` must use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag.

Comment: Actually, I have already add launchMode in manifest:
`android:launchMode = "singleTop"` But it doesn't work.